# ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded (Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException)

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-6, devart

First dataaccess method using entityframework fluent api , Dev Art in oracle database getting below error.

actual table design :

[image]

this query failing.

```
  CREATE TABLE DADeskSettings ( 
  UserID NVARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  Password NVARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  DADeskURL NVARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  WebURL NVARCHAR2(2000) NOT NULL,
  IsDADeskSettings NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  DAType VARCHAR2(4 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  UPDATEDADESK NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,
  isshortseavoy NUMBER(1) NULL,
  CreatedBy VARCHAR2(8 CHAR) NULL,
  UpdatedBy VARCHAR2(8 CHAR) NULL,
  CONSTRAINT PK_DADeskSettings PRIMARY KEY (UserID, Password, DADeskURL, WebURL, IsDADeskSettings, DAType)
)

ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded
```

but it works with entityframework edmx model + devArt. any suggestions?

```
var dummy2 = ContextFactory.Db.GetQuery<OPRPortCall>().Select(x=>x.AccountCode).FirstOrDefault(); //this is one of the line.


    *** Client Application Says ***

- ORA-01450: maximum key length (6398) exceeded  (Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleException)

- The type initializer for 'Server.ManagerService.Registers.LookupVmSvc' threw an exception.  (System.TypeInitializationException)

- Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.  (System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)



Stacktrace 
*** Client Application Says ***

   at Devart.Data.Oracle.bh.d(Int32 A_0)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.de.a(Int32 A_0, z A_1)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable disposable, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, Boolean nonQuery)
   at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Devart.Common.Entity.ej.a(DbConnection A_0, Nullable`1 A_1, b3 A_2)
   at Devart.Common.Entity.ej.a(DbConnection A_0, Nullable`1 A_1)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices.DbCreateDatabase(DbConnection connection, Nullable`1 commandTimeout, StoreItemCollection storeItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseOperations.Create(ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState)
   at System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformInitializationAction(Action action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.PerformDatabaseInitialization()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryAction`1.PerformAction(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeDatabaseAction(Action`1 action)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.AsNoTracking()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.AsNoTracking()
   at Server.Manager.DataAccess.VMEntities.GetQuery[T](Boolean tracking)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Please enable the dbMonitor tool and specify the exact SQL statement which fails to execute: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?dbmonitor.html.
2. Try setting config.CodeFirstOptions.TruncateLongDefaultNames=true. Does this help?
   https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?CodeFirstOptions.html

Comment: added query which throws error on issue description,    config.CodeFirstOptions.TruncateLongDefaultNames=true doesnt help

Comment: any other possiblities?

Comment: You are using Code-First Approach (the database structure is generated in runtime), aren't you?

There are two alternative ways to solve the issue:

1) upgrade to 9.4.280 or higher to get a fix
https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/revision_history.html
9.4.280 25-May-17
The support of EF Core models with string columns, which are defined without length limit and participate in PKs, FKs, indices, is improved

2) add a length size to your mapping so that the total length of all columns participating in PK would not exceed the 6398 limit

Comment: No, we don't use code first approach. database already exists. we use just use fluent api for mapping and configuration. application running with admin account.

Comment: Here is an example of fluent mapping in the OnModelCreating method: 

      builder.Entity<YourEntityName>()
        .Property(p => p.YourPropertyName)
        .HasMaxLength(YourValue);

Answer (score 1):

- It seems you use an oracle db of version 9.2, 10 or 11 with block
  size 8k. Use smaller key index. You may diminish the initial size of
  index, when you recreate the indexes of your problematic table ( call *your_table* ).
- Alternatively, create a tablespace with non-standard, bigger block size and
  create the corresponding index on that tablespace, like in the
  example :

> ```
> SQL> create tablespace TS_DATA_16 datafile '+DATA' size 100M blocksize 16k;
> SQL> alter user your_schema quota unlimited on TS_DATA_16;
> SQL> drop table your_table;
> SQL> create table your_table
>      (
>       ...
>      )
>       tablespace TS_DATA_16;
> ```